# Why do I get black dotted lines on my mesh when switching to look dev mode?

Tags: modeling, 3d-view, shaders

[image]

I just modeled this thing, but when I switch to dev look mode these black lines on the side of the mesh. What are those and how do I get rid of them? I used the knife tool to add edges to get clean quads. Is it related to that?

Comment: I just modeled this thing, but when I switch to dev look mode these black lines on the side of the mesh. What are those and how do I get rid of them? I used the knife tool to add edges to get clean quads. Is it related to that?

Comment: Difficult to tell just from the image can you share the blend file?

Answer (score 0):

(Assuming Blender 2.80)
Looks like there are two edges at (nearly) the same place. Go edit mode and "Merge Vertice->by Distance". Play around with the distance value a little bit. Make a backup of the file before.

Answer (score 0):

I played a bit around and found the problem. I've added new edges by connection to Points with <kbd>F</kbd>  but this created a direct connection which interfered with the rest of the mesh.

I've solved it by just using the *Knife Tool* instead, but is there an easier way than the knife tool?

Comment: I like to add edges using a custom shortcut for the Subdivide tool. If you are in edge mode, go to Edge -> (and right-click) Subdivide. You will get the option to set a shortcut. I use alt-W because somebody else suggested it and it works well for me (deliberate, fast, no conflicts). You can quickly connect any two edges, double-tap "G" to slide them along those edges, and can insert 1 to 10 edges at a time.